# Como obter informações de compartilhamentos no facebook com R?

Tags: r, facebook

Gostaria de saber como consigo obter informações sobre compartilhamentos de posts no Facebook, tais como nome e id dos usuários e data e hora do compartilhamento.

No pacote `RFacebook` é possível obter as mesmas informações, mas referentes as curtidas e aos comentários, e não aos compartilhamentos.

No Facebook esse tipo de dado é público se você informar a publicação que você tem interesse.

Comment: Acredito que não basta a informação ser pública, mas sim estar disponível na [API do facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api). Aqui não encontrei nada relacionado aos compartilhamentos

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você precisa pegar os `posts` da pessoa que você quer usando o `getPage` para ter acesso a `timeline`, depois que você conseguir o `ID` da postagem que você deseja precisa utilizar o `Object SharedPosts` diretamente na `API HTTP do facebook`, infelizmente o pacote `RFacebook` ainda não dá suporte a esse `objeto`.

```
 GET /v2.5/{object-id}/sharedposts HTTP/1.1
 Host: graph.facebook.com
```

Sendo o `ObjectID` o `post` que você quer obter informações de compartilhamento.

Para mais informações eu sugiro você consultar o endereço:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/sharedposts

;)